# Select Nth child Node in HTML Document

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an html document that I need to grab all `table` elements that are the 5th table deep in the `DOM`, not to be confused with the 5th child `table`. My problem is this 5 `table` deep structure could be wrapped in any number of `div` elements so I can't use an absolute path such as

> /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table

For example:

```
<body>    
    <table>    
        <table>
            <table>
                <table>
                   <!--Grab this one -->
                   <table>
                   </table>
                </table>
            </table>
       </table>
    </table>
</body>
```

Or This:

```
 <body> 
    <div> <!--Could be wrapped more than just once though -->  
        <table>    
            <table>
                <table>
                    <table>
                       <!--Grab this one -->
                       <table>
                       </table>
                    </table>
                </table>
           </table>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//table[count(ancestor::table) = 4])[1]
```

This selects the first `table` in the document that has exactly four ancestors named `table` .

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'd want the `//` expression between each element, making the full expression:

```
//table//table//table//table//table
```

This will select any table that has 4 tables anywhere in its path

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(yourXml); 
var requiredTable = doc.Descendants("table").ElementAt(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

for mshtml (because you question is c# and html tagged) the way to access a html childnode element is something like mentioned here:
  [How can I retrieve all the text nodes of a HTMLDocument in the fastest way in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117186/how-can-i-retreive-all-the-text-nodes-of-a-htmldocument-in-the-fastest-way-in-c)

maybe this helps!